# How to write a program that reads the text file line by line and remove all the 'the' words and write it to another file

Tags: python, file-handling

How to do this program ? I've used many ways but it doesn't work.This is the code.

```
def remove():
    f1=open("Sample.txt",'r')
    x=f1.read()
    x.split()
    f2=open("Result.txt",'w')
    for i in x:
        if 'the' not in i:
            f2.write(i)
            print(f2) # This is to view the result.
   f2.close()
   f1.close()
f2=open("Result.txt",'r')
f2.read()

remove()
```

Comment: Are you need to write if the line including with "the" or replace the with empty ? and missing new line "\n"

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens when you run it, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? Please see [ask].

Comment: It works but doesn't show any output in the text document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're after, but maybe something like this:

```
text = open('Sample.txt', 'r').read()
text = text.replace('the', '')
with open('Result.txt', 'w') as f2:
    f2.write(text)
```

Comment: Regex replace would probably be more complete.
`text = re.sub(r' ?[Tt]he ?', ' ', text)`